# GLightbox and HTML5 videos - how can I set a poster image?

Tags: html5-video, lightbox

I am using GLightbox in a project I am working on.  I have a hyperlink that has a URL to a self-hosted MP4 video.  The video is opened in a GLightbox.  I have poster images already setup for my videos, but I can't figure out where to set the poster image in the Glightbox setup.  Here is my html link that launches the video in the lightbox.

```
<a href="<?= $video_url; ?>" class="standard-lightbox">
```

Here is the javascript configuration I have in my site.js file:

```
let standardLightboxSlideHTML = `<div class="gslide">
   <div class="gslide-inner-content">
       <div class="ginner-container">
           <div class="gslide-media">
           </div>
           <div class="gslide-description">
               <div class="gdesc-inner">
                   <h4 class="gslide-title"></h4>
                   <div class="gslide-desc"></div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>`;

   var standardLightbox = GLightbox({
    selector: '.standard-lightbox',
    width: '1280px',
    height: '720px',
    skin: 'modern',
    closeOnOutsideClick: true,
    slideHTML: standardLightboxSlideHTML,
    type:'video',
    autoplayVideos: false,
    
    plyr: {
      config: {
        ratio: '16:9', // or '4:3'
        muted: false,
        hideControls: false,
        autoplay: false,
        autopause: true,
        volume: 0.5,
        controls: ['play-large', 'play','progress','volume','mute','fullscreen']        
      }
    }
  });
```

I have tried adding a data-poster value to the hyperlink.  That didn't work.  That is where I would like to set it and then I want to GLightbox to use it.  Any ideas how to make that work?

I want to tag this post as "glightbox", but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my problem this way.

In wordpress I setup two new fields, one for the url to the video and another for the poster image.

I changed my code to output the url and poster urls in the hyperlink that is clicked.

In my Glightbox setup, I just grab those values and add it dynamically with javascript to the video tag.  I also add a counter to the hyperlink so I can append the count value to create an ID selector for the video.

```
standardLightbox.on('slide_after_load', (data) => {

    const { slideIndex, slideNode, slideConfig, player, trigger } = data;
   
    var btnClicked = document.getElementById(trigger.id);
    var posterimage = btnClicked.getAttribute('data-html5videoposter');
    var videoid = btnClicked.getAttribute('data-videoid');

    // use the index
    var getVideoTag = document.getElementById(videoid);
    getVideoTag.setAttribute('poster', posterimage);

});
```